# fast reacting color sensor

Tags: sensors

I want to recognize the color of passing by objects. The speed of the objects is quite fast, arround 1 meters per second maybe a bit slower. The objects can have only two colors, as an example red or green and the distance between the sensor and the passing by objects is only a few millimeter.

I want to use a color sensor or multiple sensors of the same type bheind each other and timed so that at least one of them take a measurement of the object.
But I dont know which sensor I should take.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this question has anything to do with Arduinos, at least not the way its currently written, but the answer is very simple look at the Pixie Cam. http://charmedlabs.com/default/pixy-cmucam5/